# Storing a Javascript function from a Java instance variable

Tags: javascript, java, rhino

I'm using Rhino to embed JS code in a Java (android) app.  I need a certain function written in Java to return a Java function to be called later by Javascript.  In order to maintain compatibility with the iOS implementation, this needs to be stored and saved in a JS function variable.  I can't figure out how to return a Java object that's treated as a JS function from Javascript.  I thought the answer to this would be to make a NativeJavaMethod,  but when I try to call one in Javascript it always says the "this" pointer is wrong.  The code I used was:

```
NativeJavaMethod("", runnable.getClass().getMethod("run"), scope);
```

Where runnable is a Runnable and scope is the top level scope.  There has to be a way to do this, what am I doing wrong?  I'm guessing its the scope, but I don't know what it wants there.

Exact message:   `org.mozilla.javascript.EvaluatorException: Java method "run" was invoked with [object Object] as "this" value that can not be converted to Java type java.lang.Runnable. (#1)`

(I have also even tried writing the runnable into a JS variable then storing runnable.run in a variable and grabbing that from Java to return.  Same problem.)

Edit:

The NativeJavaMethod is returned from a Java function to the caller (which is written in JavaScript), stored in a variable, then later executed. So in JS

```
var x=myobject.makeFunction();  //makeFunction is in Java, is properly called and returns the NativeJavaMethod
x();  //This throws the above exception
```

Comment: I'm returning it (this function itself was called from Javascript) storing it in a JS variable, then calling that variable.   so  var x=SomeJavaMethodThatReturnsNativeObject();   x(); in JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to do it by creating an object that extends `BaseFunction` and overriding the `call` function to call runnable.run() on the object I want to run.  I could further generify this by making it take an instance and a Method, but I don't need that at the moment.  I am still interested in better/built in answers, but this does work:

```
public static class WrapperRunnableFunction extends BaseFunction {
    Runnable runnable;
    WrapperRunnableFunction(Runnable runnable) {
        this.runnable = runnable;
    }

    @Override
    public Object call(Context cx, Scriptable scope, Scriptable thisObj, java.lang.Object[] args) {
        runnable.run();
        return null;
    }
}
```